# Having difficulty FOILing terms with Cosine or Sine functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Here is the function I need to find $f'(x)$ of:

$ f(x) =\left(\frac{x\cos\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)+1}\right)$

The derivative of the numerator is:

$ \cos \left(x\right)-x\sin \left(x\right)$

The derivative of the denominator is:

$ \cos \left(x\right)$

I know that I need to differentiate this using the quotient rule...but when it comes to foiling the top, which is the following:

$ \left[\cos\left(x\right)-x\sin\left(x\right)\right]\left[\sin\left(x\right)+1\right]-\left[x\cos\left(x\right)\right]\left[\cos\left(x\right)\right]$

...I'm stumped. I know how to FOIL, but when cosines and sines enter the picture I get beyond confused. Especially with expressions like $x\cos x$. I have no idea how to multiply any of these terms by another other term in the above expression. Could someone walk me through how to do this, and also point me towards what area of math this touches upon (so I can brush up on some review)? Also, does it suffice to leave the bottom as $\left(\sin \left(x\right)+1\right)^2$ in my final answer? Thank you!

Comment: What does "foiling" mean ?

Comment: @Peter distributing the product of binomials; FOIL = First, Outer, Inner, Last.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "foil" (a horrible word designed to make gullible middle school students believe multiplying two sums is something horribly complex and impenetrable where they need to remember a particular arbitrary order of the terms, despite the well-known fact that the order of terms **does not matter**) anything? $x\cos(x)$ is $x$ multiplied by $\cos(x)$; when you multiply that by $\cos(x)$ once more you get $x\cos(x)\cos(x)$ which is also often written as $x\cos^2(x)$.

Comment: Another hint useful in this case : $$(\sin(x))^2+(\cos(x))^2=1$$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yep, "FOIL" is the f-word in my classes.  My students are not so stupid that they can't understand the distributive property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this question is that the algebra to simply the solution is *very* long and annoying, so if you're struggling with multiplying the brackets out then it will take some time. To perhaps point you in the right direction, recall that if we can write
$$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd.$$
Think of the sines and cosines just like you do with the $a$'s and $b$'s. So, in your question, you can write, using your FOIL convention
$$(\cos x-x\sin x)(\sin x+1)=\underbrace{\cos x\sin x}_{\text{F}}+\underbrace{\cos x}_{\text{O}}-\underbrace{x\sin^2 x}_{\text{I}}-\underbrace{x\sin x}_{\text{L}}.$$
Here, we use $\sin^2x=\sin x\cdot \sin x$ which I am sure you are familiar with. Therefore, after using the quotient rule, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin x}&=\frac{\cos x\sin x+\cos x-x\sin^2 x-x\sin x-\color{red}{(x\cos x)(\cos x)}}{(1+\sin x)^2}\\
&=\frac{\cos x\sin x+\cos x-x\sin^2 x-x\sin x-\color{red}{x\cos^2 x}}{(1+\sin x)^2}\\
&=\frac{\cos x\sin x+\cos x-x\sin x-x(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)}{(1+\sin x)}\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{\cos x\sin x+\cos x}-\color{purple}{x\sin x-x}}{(1+\sin x)^2}\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}-\color{purple}{x(\sin x+1)}}{(1+\sin x)^2}\\
&=\frac{\cos x-x}{1+\sin x}.
\end{align}
Note that I have included colours to show you what I did to certain terms on the following lines.

The trick here is using a lot of trigonometric identities to simplify matters step by step. For instance, if you see a $\sin^2x$ and a $\cos^2 x$, see if you can group them to utilize $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for this answer. I was ripping my hair out trying to do this in a purely algebraic way, but these trig identities are hugely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

1. Use the quotient rule:
   $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{f(x)}{y(x)}\right)=\frac{y(x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(f(x)\right)-f(x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)\right)}{y(x)^2}=\frac{y(x)f'(x)-f(x)y'(x)}{y(x)^2}$$
2. Differentiate the sum term by term, when $\text{C}$ is a constant:
   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\text{C}+z(x)\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(z(x)\right)=z'(x)$$
3. Use the product rule:
   $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(xr(x)\right)=x\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(r(x)\right)+r(x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)=xr'(x)+r(x)$$

Because:

- $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(1)=0$$
- $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your real question is that the way to multiply things together is to just write them next to each other.  $5$ times $x$ is $5x$.  And $x\cos x$ times $\sin x$ is $x \cos x \sin x.$  Then simplify if you can.